# all the zero points of $1 + \frac 1 z + \frac 1 {2!z^2} + \cdots + \frac 1{n!z^n}$ satisfy $\lvert z \rvert \lt \delta$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Prove: For every $\delta \gt 0$, there is a natural number $n$, such that all the zero points of $1 + \frac 1 z + \frac 1 {2!z^2} + \cdots + \frac 1{n!z^n}$ satisfy $\lvert z \rvert \lt \delta$.

Then the answer goes:

If $\delta$ is small enough, $$e^z = 1 + z  + {z^2 \over 2!}+ \cdots + {z^n \over n!}+ \cdots$$ is uniformly convergent on $\lvert z \rvert \le \delta^{-1}$.

So is $$e^{\frac 1 z} =1 + \frac 1 z + \frac 1 {2!z^2} + \cdots + \frac 1{n!z^n} + \cdots$$ on $\lvert z \rvert \ge \delta$.

By [Cauchy's convergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_convergence_test), there exists one $N = N(\delta)$, such that when $n \gt N$, $\lvert{\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty {1 \over {k!z^k}} \rvert}\lt \frac m 2$ $(\lvert z \rvert \ge \delta)$. 
Then 
$$\inf_{\lvert z \rvert \ge \delta} \lvert e^{1 \over z}\rvert = \inf_{\lvert z \rvert \le \delta^{-1}} \lvert e^z\rvert \equiv m.$$(I don't know how this equation is drawn.I don't know much about infimum ...)

So, $$\lvert 1 + \frac 1 z + \frac 1 {2!z^2} + \cdots + \frac 1{n!z^n} \rvert \ge \lvert e^{1 \over z}\rvert - \lvert\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty {1 \over {k!z^k}} \rvert \gt m - \frac m 2 = \frac m 2 \gt 0(\lvert z \rvert \ge \delta).$$

Qed.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: I don't know why $\inf \equiv m$.

Comment: It's the other way. $m$ is **defined to be** $\displaystyle \inf_{|z| \leqslant \delta^{-1}} |e^z|$ and then we pick $N$ so that $$\left| \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k! z^k} \right| < \frac{m}{2}$$ whenever $n \geqslant N$. I mean, it's very unclear from the wording that $\inf$ is the definition of $m$, but that was certainly the intention.

Comment: @Adayah Aha, so it is. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, contrary to what's stated, Cauchy's convergence test is not used here. It's a straighforward application of the definition that since $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k! \cdot z^k} \rightrightarrows e^{\frac{1}{z}},$$ there is $N$ such that $$\left| \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k! \cdot z^k} \right| = \left| \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k! \cdot z^k} - e^{\frac{1}{z}} \right| < \frac{m}{2}$$ whenever $n \geqslant N$ (all for $|z| \geqslant \delta$)